# Apple rules for publishing user's app review on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, review

The app I am maintaining has 12 user's reviews. App Store is showing only 1 review. 
More details:
 - 10 out of 12 reviews were added to App Store at least month ago.
 - the only 1 review that is shown on App Store is added a year ago.
 - Several new versions of the applications were published in the meantime.

How Apple select user's review which will be publicly shown on App Store?

Note: I found the info that Apple is taking action against fake ratings/reviews [here](https://techcrunch.com/2014/06/13/apple-is-taking-action-against-fake-ratings-on-the-app-store/). Still there is no info on what rules are applied for publishing someone's comment about rated app.

Answer (score 2):

You only see reviews for the country you open the appStore from , you can see all of them in ItunesConnect

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted Apple regarding this question and their comments are listed below:

- Customers are permitted to leave a rating for your application
  without leaving a written review.
- If a user is having trouble leaving reviews, please direct them to
  contact iTunes.
- Customers can rate and review your book only once. If they review
  your app a second time, the new review replaces the old one.
- Ratings and reviews apply only to the territory in which the book
  purchase or download was made.  On the Customer Reviews page in
  iTunes Connect, select a territory in which your book is available
  for sale to view customer reviews for   that territory. Customer
  reviews won’t appear in all storefronts worldwide.

After contacting Apple and directing them to specific reviews that were left for the app, the new reviews start appearing. I do not have explanation on what did the magic, but in such cases **I suggest contacting Apple and directing them to specific review which is left so that they can analyze it.**